# My form is not submitting, its giving only default value not exact match

Tags: php, forms

PHP form is not submitting. When i click on report by block/GP option and select optiond and submit then its not showing any result just giving default value. This code is working fine at my localhost.

```js
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getXMLHTTP() { //fuction to return the xml http object
  var xmlhttp=false; 
  try{
   xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
  catch(e) {  
   try{   
    xmlhttp= new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
   catch(e){
    try{
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e1){
     xmlhttp=false;
    }
   }
  }
    
  return xmlhttp;
    }

 
 function getState(districtId) {  
  
  var strURL="http://sbmpunjab.com/sbmpunjab/website_control/admin_form/constituency_report.php?district="+districtId;
  var req = getXMLHTTP();
  
  if (req) {
   
   req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
     // only if "OK"
     if (req.status == 200) {

             var returnedData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);
             $('#Constituencydiv select[name=constituency]').html(returnedData.constituency);
             $('#Blockdiv').html(returnedData.block);
             $('#Divisionsdiv select[name=divisions]').html(returnedData.divisions);

                                                document.getElementById('GramPanchdiv').innerHTML='<select name="grampanch"><option>Select Gram Panchayat</option></select>';   
  
     } else {
      alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
     }
    }    
   }   
   req.open("GET", strURL, true);
   req.send(null);
  }  
 }

 function getCity(districtId,blockId) {  
  var 
  strURL="http://sbmpunjab.com/sbmpunjab/website_control/admin_form/village_report.php?district="+districtId+"&block="+blockId;
    
  var req = getXMLHTTP();
  
  if (req) {
   
   req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (req.readyState == 4) {
     // only if "OK"
     if (req.status == 200) { 
      var returnedData = JSON.parse(req.responseText);     
   $('#GramPanchdiv select[name=grampanch]').html(returnedData.GramPanch);          
     } else {
      alert("Problem while using XMLHTTP:\n" + req.statusText);
     }
    }    
   }   
   req.open("GET", strURL, true);
   req.send(null);
  }
    
 }
 
 </script>

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td height="20" colspan="2" align="center">
  <h4>Beneficiary Report</h4>
 </td>
 </tr>
 <br />
 
 <? if($Section=='' || $Section=='SearchBlock'){?>
 <tr>
  <td><b>Search options</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <a href="<?=DIR_WS_SITE_CONTROL?>index.php?Page=<?=$Page?>&search=block">Report by Block/GP</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
  
  </td><br/>
 </tr>
 <?}?>

 <?php $search =isset($_GET['search'])?$_GET['search']:"";
  
  if($search=='block'){?>
<tr>
 <td>
 <form id="searchBform" name="searchBform" action="<?=DIR_WS_SITE_CONTROL?>index.php?Page=<?=$Page?>&Section=SearchBlock1" method="POST">

  <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" width="100%" class="InsideTable">
  
   <tr>
    <td width="20%" class="InsideLeftTd"><b>District</b></td>
    <td class="InsideRightTd">
      <select name="district" id="district" title="Please select district." onChange="getState(this.value)">
      <?
     $DefaultDistrict = isset($_POST['district'])?MyStripSlashes($_POST['district']):(isset($CurrentBF->district_id)?MyStripSlashes($CurrentBF->district_id):DEFINE_DEFAULT_DISTRICT);
     $DistrictObj = new DataTable(TABLE_DISTRICT);
     $DistrictObj->TableSelectAll("","district ASC");
     while ($CurrentDistrict = $DistrictObj->GetObjectFromRecord())
     {
      ?>
      <option value="<?=$CurrentDistrict->id?>" <?=$DefaultDistrict==$CurrentDistrict->id?"selected":""?>><?=$CurrentDistrict->district?></option>
      <?
     }
     ?>
     </select>
    </td>
   </tr>

 <?php 
if(isset($CurrentBF->district_id) && $CurrentBF->district_id!='0'){

$BlockObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BLOCKS);
$BlockObj ->Where ="district_id='".$CurrentBF->district_id."'";
$BlockObj->TableSelectAll();
}


?>

   <tr>
    <td width="20%" class="InsideLeftTd"><b>Block</b></td>
    <td class="InsideRightTd">
    <div id="Blockdiv">
       <? if(isset($CurrentBF->district_id) && $CurrentBF->district_id!='0'){?>
       <select name="block" onchange="getCity('<?php echo $CurrentBF->district_id; ?>', this.value)" >
  

   <?while ($CurrentBlock = $BlockObj->GetObjectFromRecord())
   {
  ?>
   <option value="<?=$CurrentBlock->id?>"<?=$CurrentBlock->id==$CurrentBF->block_id ? "selected":""?>> <?=$CurrentBlock->block_name ?></option>
  <?
   }
   ?>  
    </select>
    <?}?>
    <option>Select Block</option>

     </div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  
   <tr>
    <td width="20%" class="InsideLeftTd"><b>Gram Panchayat</b></td>
    <td class="InsideRightTd">
    <div id="GramPanchdiv">

    <select name="grampanch" >
           
    <option>Select Gram Panchayat</option>
      
     
    </select></div>
   </tr>

   <tr>
   <td><input type="submit" name="submit" title="Search"></td>
   </tr>

   </table>
   </form>
  </td>
 </tr>
 
 
 <?}?>


 <tr><td><br/></td></tr>
</table>

<?php
//// Section start
switch($Section)
{
 case "district_report":
 default:

 
  $DistrictObj = new DataTable(TABLE_DISTRICT);
  $DistrictObj->Where = "1";
  $DistrictObj->TableSelectAll();

?>
 
 <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="0" class="InsideTable">
   
    <tr class="InsideLeftTd">
    <td width="2%" height="25"><b>S.No</b></td>
    <td width="10%" align="left"><b>District</b></td>
     <td width="8%" align="left"><b>Number of beneficiaries Entered online</b></td>
    <td width="10%" align="left"><b>Number Beneficiaries  whose picture uploaded</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number beneficiaries whose electricity bill uploaded</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number beneficiaries whose bank pass book uploaded</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number of Picture stage 1 uploaded</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number of Picture stage 2 uploaded</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number of Picture stage 3 uploaded</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number of latrines for which Ist Installment issue</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number of latrines for which IInd Installment issue</b></td>
    
   </tr>
<?
  
 $SNo=1;
 $Count=1;
 while($CurrentDis=$DistrictObj->GetObjectFromRecord())
 {
   
    $bObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->id."'";
    $bObj->TableSelectAll("","");

    $bObj1 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj1->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND beneficiary_image!=''";
    $bObj1->TableSelectAll("","");

       $bObj2 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj2->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND elec_bill_image!=''";
    $bObj2->TableSelectAll("","");

    $bObj3 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj3->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND bank_pass_book_image!=''";
    $bObj3->TableSelectAll("","");
    
    
  $ImgObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='1' AND bimg.Image !=''";
  $ImgObj->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj1 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj1->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj1->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='2' AND bimg.Image !=''";
  $ImgObj1->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj2 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj2->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj2->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='3' AND bimg.Image !=''";
  $ImgObj2->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj3 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj3->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj3->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='2' AND bimg.Complete='1'";
  $ImgObj3->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj4 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj4->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj4->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='3' AND bimg.Complete='1'";
  $ImgObj4->TableSelectAll();

 
?>
 <tr class="InsideRightTd">
  <td height="25" align="center" style="color:black"><?=$SNo?>.</td>
  <td align="left" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($CurrentDis->district);?></td>

  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($bObj->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($bObj1->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($bObj2->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($bObj3->GetNumRows())?></td>

  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($ImgObj->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($ImgObj1->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($ImgObj2->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($ImgObj3->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($ImgObj4->GetNumRows())?></td>

 </tr>
<? 
 $SNo++;
 $Count++;
} 

  $bObj1 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
  $bObj1->Where = "1";
  $bObj1->TableSelectAll();

     $bObj12 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
  $bObj12->Where = "beneficiary_image!=''";
  $bObj12->TableSelectAll("","");

     $bObj23 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
  $bObj23->Where = "elec_bill_image!=''";
  $bObj23->TableSelectAll("","");

  $bObj34 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
  $bObj34->Where = "bank_pass_book_image!=''";
  $bObj34->TableSelectAll("","");
    
  
  $IObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES);
  $IObj ->Where ="Stage='1' AND Image !=''";
  $IObj->TableSelectAll();
 
  $IObj1 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES);
  $IObj1 ->Where ="Stage='2' AND Image !=''";
  $IObj1->TableSelectAll();

  $IObj2 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES);
  $IObj2 ->Where ="Stage='3' AND Image !=''";
  $IObj2->TableSelectAll();

     $IObj3 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES);
  $IObj3 ->Where ="Stage='2' AND Complete='1'";
  $IObj3->TableSelectAll();

  $IObj4 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES);
  $IObj4 ->Where ="Stage='3' AND Complete='1'";
  $IObj4->TableSelectAll();


?>
<tr>
 <td colspan="10"><hr></td>
</tr>
<tr class="InsideRightTd">
 <td height="25" align="center"></td>
 <td align="left"><b>Total</b></td>
 <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($bObj1->GetNumRows())?></td>

 <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($bObj12->GetNumRows())?></td>
 <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($bObj23->GetNumRows())?></td>
 <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($bObj34->GetNumRows())?></td>

 <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($IObj->GetNumRows())?></td>
 <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($IObj1->GetNumRows())?></td>
 <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($IObj2->GetNumRows())?></td>
 <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($IObj3->GetNumRows())?></td>
 <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($IObj4->GetNumRows())?></td>

</tr>


</table>

<?php
 break;

case "SearchBlock1" :

  $did = isset($_REQUEST['district'])?$_REQUEST['district']:"";
  $bid = isset($_REQUEST['block'])?$_REQUEST['block']:"";
  $gpid= isset($_REQUEST['grampanch'])?$_REQUEST['grampanch']:"";
  
  
   
 if(isset($bid) && $bid!='' && isset($gpid) && $gpid!=''){
  $searchIDObj = new DataTable(TABLE_GRAM_PANCHAYAT);
  $searchIDObj->Where ="block_id='".$bid."' AND id='".$gpid."'";

 }elseif(isset($bid) && $bid!=''){
  $searchIDObj = new DataTable(TABLE_GRAM_PANCHAYAT);
  $searchIDObj->Where ="block_id='".$bid."'";
 
 }else{
  $searchIDObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BLOCKS);
   $searchIDObj->Where ="district_id='".$did."'";
 }

  $searchIDObj->TableSelectAll("","id ASC");
 
  if($searchIDObj->GetNumRows() > 0)
  {
  ?>

 <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" border="0" class="InsideTable">
   
    <tr class="InsideLeftTd">
    <td width="2%" height="25"><b>S.No</b></td>

 <?if(isset($bid) && $bid!='' && isset($gpid) && $gpid!=''){?>
    <td width="10%" align="left"><b>District</b></td>
    <td width="10%" align="left"><b>Block</b></td>
    <td width="10%" align="left"><b>GP</b></td>

 <?}elseif(isset($bid) && $bid!=''){?>
  <td width="10%" align="left"><b>District</b></td>
  <td width="10%" align="left"><b>Block</b></td>
  <td width="10%" align="left"><b>GP</b></td>
  
 <?}else{?>
  <td width="10%" align="left"><b>District</b></td>
    <td width="10%" align="left"><b>Block</b></td>
 <?}?>
     <td width="8%" align="left"><b>Number of beneficiaries Entered online</b></td>
    <td width="10%" align="left"><b>Number Beneficiaries  whose picture uploaded</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number beneficiaries whose electricity bill uploaded</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number beneficiaries whose bank pass book uploaded</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number of Picture stage 1 uploaded</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number of Picture stage 2 uploaded</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number of Picture stage 3 uploaded</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number of latrines for which Ist Installment issue</b></td>
    <td width="15%"><b>Number of latrines for which IInd Installment issue</b></td>
    
   </tr>
<?
  
 $SNo=1;
 $Count=1;
 while($CurrentDis=$searchIDObj->GetObjectFromRecord())
 {

 if(isset($CurrentDis->id) && $CurrentDis->id!='' && isset($CurrentDis->block_id) && $CurrentDis->block_id!=''){
   
    $bObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj->Where = "village_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND block_id='".$CurrentDis->block_id."' ";
    $bObj->TableSelectAll("","");

    $bObj1 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj1->Where = "block_id='".$CurrentDis->block_id."' AND village_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND beneficiary_image!=''";
    $bObj1->TableSelectAll("","");

       $bObj2 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj2->Where = "block_id='".$CurrentDis->block_id."' AND village_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND elec_bill_image!=''";
    $bObj2->TableSelectAll("","");

    $bObj3 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj3->Where = "block_id='".$CurrentDis->block_id."' AND village_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND bank_pass_book_image!=''";
    $bObj3->TableSelectAll("","");
    
    
  $ImgObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj->Where ="b.block_id='".$ImgObj->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->block_id)."' AND b.village_id='".$ImgObj->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='1' AND bimg.Image !=''";
  $ImgObj->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj1 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj1->Where ="b.block_id='".$ImgObj->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->block_id)."' AND b.village_id='".$ImgObj->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='2' AND bimg.Image !=''";
  $ImgObj1->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj2 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj2->Where ="b.block_id='".$ImgObj->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->block_id)."' AND b.village_id='".$ImgObj->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='3' AND bimg.Image !=''";
  $ImgObj2->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj3 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj3->Where ="b.block_id='".$ImgObj->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->block_id)."' AND b.village_id='".$ImgObj->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='2' AND bimg.Complete='1'";
  $ImgObj3->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj4 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj4->Where ="b.block_id='".$ImgObj->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->block_id)."' AND b.village_id='".$ImgObj->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='3' AND bimg.Complete='1'";
  $ImgObj4->TableSelectAll();

 }elseif(isset($CurrentDis->id) && $CurrentDis->id!='' && isset($CurrentDis->district_id) && $CurrentDis->district_id!=''){

  $bObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj->Where = "block_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND district_id='".$CurrentDis->district_id."' ";
    $bObj->TableSelectAll("","");
  
  $bObj1 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj1->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->district_id."' AND block_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND beneficiary_image!=''";
    $bObj1->TableSelectAll("","");

       $bObj2 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj2->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->district_id."' AND block_id='".$CurrentDis->id."'AND elec_bill_image!=''";
    $bObj2->TableSelectAll("","");

    $bObj3 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj3->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->district_id."' AND block_id='".$CurrentDis->id."'AND bank_pass_book_image!=''";
    $bObj3->TableSelectAll("","");
    
    
  $ImgObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->district_id)."' AND b.block_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND bimg.Stage='1' AND bimg.Image !=''";
  $ImgObj->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj1 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj1->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj1->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->district_id)."' AND b.block_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND bimg.Stage='2' AND bimg.Image !=''";
  $ImgObj1->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj2 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj2->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj2->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->district_id)."' AND b.block_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND bimg.Stage='3' AND bimg.Image !=''";
  $ImgObj2->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj3 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj3->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj3->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->district_id)."' AND b.block_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND bimg.Stage='2' AND bimg.Complete='1'";
  $ImgObj3->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj4 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj4->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj4->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->district_id)."' AND b.block_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND bimg.Stage='3' AND bimg.Complete='1'";
  $ImgObj4->TableSelectAll();
 
 }else{

    $bObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->id."'";
    $bObj->TableSelectAll("","");

    $bObj1 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj1->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND beneficiary_image!=''";
    $bObj1->TableSelectAll("","");

       $bObj2 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj2->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND elec_bill_image!=''";
    $bObj2->TableSelectAll("","");

    $bObj3 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY);
    $bObj3->Where = "district_id='".$CurrentDis->id."' AND bank_pass_book_image!=''";
    $bObj3->TableSelectAll("","");
    
    
  $ImgObj = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='1' AND bimg.Image !=''";
  $ImgObj->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj1 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj1->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj1->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='2' AND bimg.Image !=''";
  $ImgObj1->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj2 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj2->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj2->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='3' AND bimg.Image !=''";
  $ImgObj2->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj3 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj3->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj3->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='2' AND bimg.Complete='1'";
  $ImgObj3->TableSelectAll();

  $ImgObj4 = new DataTable(TABLE_BENEFICIARY." b INNER JOIN ".TABLE_BENEFICIARY_IMAGES." bimg on (b.id = bimg.beneficiary_id)");
  $ImgObj4->Where ="b.district_id='".$ImgObj4->MysqlEscapeString($CurrentDis->id)."' AND bimg.Stage='3' AND bimg.Complete='1'";
  $ImgObj4->TableSelectAll();
 }

 
?>
 <tr class="InsideRightTd">
  <td height="25" align="center" style="color:black"><?=$SNo?>.</td>
 
 <?if(isset($CurrentDis->id) && $CurrentDis->id!='' && isset($CurrentDis->village_name) && $CurrentDis->village_name!=''){?>
  <td align="left" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($CurrentDis->district_name);?></td>
  <td align="left" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($CurrentDis->block_name);?></td>
  <td align="left" style="color:black"><a href="<?=DIR_WS_SITE_CONTROL?>index.php?Page=beneficiary&Section=SearchBlock&block=<?=$CurrentDis->block_id?>&grampanch=<?=$CurrentDis->id?>"><?=MyStripSlashes($CurrentDis->village_name);?></a></td>

 <?}elseif(isset($CurrentDis->id) && $CurrentDis->id!='' && isset($CurrentDis->block_name) && $CurrentDis->block_name!=''){?>
  <td align="left" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($CurrentDis->district_name);?></td>
  <td align="left" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($CurrentDis->block_name);?></td>

 <?}else{?>
  
  <td align="left" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($CurrentDis->district);?></td>

 <?}?>

  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($bObj->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($bObj1->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($bObj2->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($bObj3->GetNumRows())?></td>

  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($ImgObj->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($ImgObj1->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($ImgObj2->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($ImgObj3->GetNumRows())?></td>
  <td align="center" style="color:black"><?=MyStripSlashes($ImgObj4->GetNumRows())?></td>

 </tr>
<? 
 $SNo++;
 $Count++;
} 
?>
</table>
 <?
  }
  else 
  {
   ?>
   <b>No Result Found.</b>
   <?
  }


 break;
}
?>
```

Comment: Any errors generated? Check your error_log.

Comment: no error is coming .........In view source , its saying Confirm Form Resubmission

ERR_CACHE_MISS

Comment: That means the page before is POSTing to it. So in chrome, press the F5 key to refresh the view source page to resend to the view source page your POST data for the view source page to show its source. Alternatively, put `header('Content-type: text/plain');` in your PHP or right click on the page, click inspect element, then click the HTML element, right click it then press edit as HTML. This will give you your page's generated HTML, factoring in run-time changes from JavaScript.

Comment: Lastly, you can also watch network traffic in chrome. `ctrl` + `shift` + `i` to open up chrome's network tab. Then on your page, click a link on your page, submit a form or refresh the page etc so requests will be made to the server. Then in your network tab, you should see all the files it requests. Look for the top-most request which should be the page you requested. Right click on it and press `copy response`. Then open your favorite text editor and paste. There's the source of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript there probably violates the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Try adding `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');` to your PHP pages which you want to give JavaScript cross-origin access, that way your Ajax request for the cross-origin page, when it attempts its initial `OPTIONS` request, will see it has permission to make a `POST` or `GET` request on it.  See [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) for info on how the `OPTIONS` request works.

You can also do this via .htaccess like so:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>
```